# Does the error "A structure tag is required when using custom permalinks." mean my permalinks haven't saved?

Tags: permalinks

I'm troubleshooting an error elsewhere in a site and apparently need to resave my permalinks (without changing them), however when I do that I get (what seems to be) an error "A structure tag is required when using custom permalinks" as shown below.

I want to know if the permalinks were resaved or not, even though I didn't change them.

The "Learn more" link that comes with the message points to [this core WordPress documentation](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/#choosing-your-permalink-structure), which seems to indicate the message is triggered by something in WordPress core, though I can't be 100% sure.

This site is running WordPress 6.0.3.

[image: Error shown when trying to save permalinks with no changes]

Comment: What custom permalink are you trying to save?

Comment: @vancoder strangely, the "Post name" option is selected, so I'm not even using the "Custom Structure" option. The theme appears to have added some additional permalink settings to the page, but the error message appears to be one from WP core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the permalinks were unsaved.

In my case, the currently selected option was "Post name". I changed to "Numeric" then clicked "Save changes" and got the same error. I then changed the selected option back to "Post name" and clicked "Save changes" again, and received a message saying it was successfully saved.

At that point, the 404 error I was getting from the default WooCommerce order-received page no longer occurred, which was the whole point of me trying to resave the permalinks.